# Mongo malformed geo-query with MultiPolygon

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I'm using `$geoWithin` on a large list of geographic regions, defined in `geoJSON`. Some of these regions are `Polygons`, and some are `MultiPolygons`.

`MultiPolygons` fail, with a non-descript `Malformed geo query` error. After experimenting with the `repl`, I found I can't get mongo to take any `MultiPolygon`.

This is a minimal example:

```
{
    "type" : "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates" : [
        [
            [
                [ 9.560016, 42.152492 ],
                [ 8.746009, 42.628122 ],
                [ 9.390001, 43.009985 ],
                [ 9.560016, 42.152492 ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

[GEOJSONLint](http://geojsonlint.com/) says it's fine, and shows me a triangle in the map, but mongo won't take it.

How is it malformed?